# Рубль, копейка, гривня

Tags: этимология, семантика

В Украине поговаривают о переименовании тамошней копейки (части гривни) в "рубль". Не хочу обсуждать актуальность этого законопроекта, хотя думаю - мертворожденный.

Вопрос в другом. Мотивировка среди прочих и та, что рубль был частью гривны, а копейка - частью рубля.

Что-то мне не нравится в этой схеме, ахронизм какой-то. Кто может дать исчерпывающую информацию о взаимоотношениях древнерусских гривны, рубля и копейки? Интересует не столько общеизвестные сведения о происхождении, сколько семантика и понимание причин выбора таких названий для дольных единиц.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рубль по одной из версий действительно был частью (половиной), которую отрубили от гривны, отсюда и название. Доподлинно это незвестно, так как источников сохранилось немного и целую гривну с XIII в. тоже могли называть рублём. Дополнительную сложность добавляет то, что гривна - это не только денежная единица, но и мера веса. Поэтому гривна серебра и гривна кун (основа денежной системы Руси) - это чаще всего различные по ценности слитки, которые могли ещё иметь и разны вес.

Другое дело, что в те времена, никаких копеек ещё не было, а когда они появились (1535 г.) уже никаких гривен не существовало (*литовские гривны*, которые тоже чаще называли *рублями* постепенно исчезли за полвека до этого).

Comment: Ясно. Я примерно так это и представлял, только не был уверен - и главное: датировок точных не имел. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Википедия имеет достаточно полные статьи про [гривну](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0) и [рубль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8C).

Comment: Здесь не принято давать ответ в виде ссылки.

Comment: Я бы рад сделать это в коментарии, но у меня нет таких прав.  Я могу только ответить на коментарий.

Comment: Кстати, здесь принято задавать вопросы, ответы на которые можно найти в сети?

Comment: Принято. И ответы давать принято на них. Только полные. А по ссылке - только источник для проверки. Кстати, в вики прямого ответа я не нашел.

Comment: Что значит "ответить на комментарий"? Вы можете комментировать собственный ответ вне всяких ограничений. И дополнять его - с помощью правки.

Comment: Да, я бы не отвечал вообще, если бы я мог просто оставить коментарий к Вашему вопросу.
Если прямого ответа Вы не нашли, то тогда можно и вопрос конкретный задать, сказав, **что** в википедии не являтся достаточно полным.  Разумеется, википедия - не самый достоверный источник, кроме того они, кажется, не специализируются на языковых темах...

Comment: А здесь можно добавлять комментарии непосредственно к вопросам - прямо под вопросом, слева, синим шрифтом - "добавить комментарий".

Comment: У него уважения не хватает, вроде, к чужим ответам комментарии давать. Наверное, и к вопросам.

Comment: Victor Bazarov, я задал достаточно прямой вопрос. Марк Из прекрасно его понял. И подтвердил мое сомнение...